# Inversions in a binary string

Tags: string, algorithm, binary, inversion

How many inversions are there in a binary string of length n ?

```
For example , n = 3
000->0
001->0
010->1
011->0
100->2
101->1
110->2
111->0
So total inversions are 6
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'inversions'?

Comment: Please show some effort. Can you make a brute force solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question looks like a homework, that's why let me *omit the details*. You can:

1. Solve the problem as a recurrency (see Толя's answer)
2. Make up and solve the characteristic equation, get the solution as a *close formula* with some arbitrary constants (`c1`, `c2`, ..., `cn`); as the matter of fact you'll get just *one* unknown constant.
3. Put some known solutions (e.g. `f(1) = 0`, `f(3) = 6`) into the formula and find out all the unknown coefficients

The final answer you should get is

```
 f(n) = n*(n-1)*2**(n-3)
```

where `**` means raising into power (`2**(n-3)` is `2` in `n-3` power). In case you don't want to deal with recurrency and the like stuff, you can just prove the formula by *induction*.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy recurrent function.
Assume that we know answer for n-1.
And after ato all previous sequences we add 0 or 1 as first character.

if we adding 0 as first character that mean that count of inversions will not be changed: hence answer will be same as for n-1.

if we adding 1 as first character that mean count of inversions will be same as before and will be added extra inversion equals to count of 0 into all previous sequences.

Count of zeros ans ones in sequences of length `n-1` will be:

```
(n-1)*2^(n-1)
```

Half of them is zeros it will give following result

```
(n-1)*2^(n-2)
```

It means that we have following formula:

```
f(1) = 0
f(n) = 2*f(n-1) + (n-1)*2^(n-2)
```

Comment: Going a bit further we can obtain the *close formula* which is `f(n) = n*(n-1)*2^(n-3)`; in case one doesn't want to solve the characterstic equation an the like stuff, he/she can just prove the solution by *induction*